# calculate total distance to travel to visit all letters of string python

Tags: python

[image]

I have inputs like 'MAMA' and 'ELECTROENCEPHALOGRAPHIC'
The task is to find the total distance to travel to visit all letters of the given string in succession, starting at the first letter of the string.
And the answers should be 36 and 108.

I tried to solve this by making two dictionaries

```
row0 = {'A':0,'B':1,'C':2,'D':3,'E':4,'F':5,'G':6,'H':7,'I':8,'J':9,'K':10,'L':11,'M':12}
row1 = {'N':1,'O':2,'P':3,'Q':4,'R':5,'S':6,'T':7,'U':8,'V':9,'W':10,'X':11,'Y':12,'Z':13}
```

But it didnt work well when the letters travel different rows..

How to do it in Python?

Comment: you already have everything - just count distance, if letter in different row - distance plus 1 for change of row

Comment: I think your second example doesn't give `108`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could look like this:

```
import string

# built char to grid position dict
grid = {c: (i // 13, i % 13) for i, c in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase)}
#   row ----^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^--- column

def distance(word):
    up = word.upper()
    def dis(c1, c2):  # distance of two chars
    #   row distance                   + column distance
        abs(grid[c1][0] - grid[c2][0]) + abs(grid[c1][1] - grid[c2][1]))

    # now sum all distances of neighbouring char pairs
    return sum(dis(c1, c2) for c1, c2 in zip(up, up[1:]))

distance('mama')
# 36
```

Comment: +1 that's a clever way of initialising a `dictionary`! I didn't know about this (I should probably use `dictionaries` more often).

Answer (score 0):

The function that will be key to us is [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord). This function takes a `string` and returns an `integer` of the `ASCII` value of it. From an [`ASCII` table](http://www.asciitable.com/), we can see that `A` is at `65`. After `65`, the next `26` are the letters in the alphabet...

Knowing this, we can start writing some `code` to find the `'distances'` between characters. To start with we define a `string` to `test` with. Next, we will `loop` through the `indexes` in the `string`, up to the `length` of the `string` `-1` because we will calculate the distance between this `index` and the `index` after.

We then want to work out the difference between the `ASCII` values of the character at this `index` and the character at the `index` after.

This would be the `'distance'` (once we take the absolute value with `abs()`), but since we are working with the `2` rows, we need to subtract `12` from the `difference` if the difference is greater than `12` (i.e. on different rows).

That may sound complicated, but should remove the need to create any `dictionaries` or `lists` that we must look things up in...

The `code` for what I just described would look something like:

```
word = "MAMA"
distance = 0

for i in range(len(word) - 1):
    diff = abs(ord(word[i+1]) - ord(word[i]))
    if diff > 12:
        diff = diff - 12
    distance += diff

print(distance)
```

which gives `36` as the `distance`.

Hope this helps! **:)**